# Converting Shell Script to Batch for Sipp

Tags: shell, batch-file, sip

This is the shell script for logging sipp output as shown in the website `http://sipp.sourceforge.net/doc/faq.html`

I have never done batch scripting before, and I am having difficulty in understanding how to convert this code to make it run in windows.

```
 cat run.sh
#!/bin/sh
>results.txt
for i in $*
do
  echo Launching test $i >> results.txt
  ./sipp -sf $i -m 1 127.0.0.1
  if test $? -ne 0
    then
        echo Test $i failed >> results.txt
    else
        echo Test $i succeeded >> results.txt
    fi
done
exit 0
```

Can somebody help me? Also what does `$*` in the for loop indicate? 
I tried the equivalent in batch for the if condition `IF %test  NEQ 0`, but it came syntax error.

Comment: I should probably have entered the comment first before putting in the answer - but you might get better help if you could specify exactly which parts you are stuck at, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

For a "direct translation" and not "bullet proof" code, you can try

```
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions

    for %%i in (%*) do (
        echo Launching test %%i >> results.tx
        .\sipp -sf %%i -m 1 127.0.0.1
        if errorlevel 1 (
            echo Test %%i failed >> results.txt
        ) else (
            echo Test %%i failed >> results.txt
        )
    )

    exit /b 0
```

Not sure it will fit into sipp, i've never used it, but this is the basic idea

Answer (score 0):

`$*`  returns to you all the input params, as a single word.

Also, as far as I know, "test" does not exist in BAT. If you want to check the exit code you can use something like `ERRORLEVEL` (check similar question https://superuser.com/questions/194662/how-to-check-the-exit-code-of-the-last-command-in-batch-file)

What you want to do is, understand the shell-script logic and then use reference sites such as http://ss64.com/nt/ to make a port of the code (while keeping in mind that it may not be a pure one-to-one port).

Also, couple of thoughts:

- Not sure if you have a Windows port of SIPP available. Might want to check that.
- Consider getting started with Powershell. It's much more versatile than BAT for sure; and might prove easier to switch to, if you come from a bash background.